# Save JSON as Domain Class with Restfull Controller in Deep

Tags: json, rest, grails

I've two domain class:

```
class A {
 String foo
 static hasMany = [children: B]
}

class B {
 String bar
 static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

I want to save A from JSON like:

```
{
 foo: "Hello world!",
 children: [
  {bar: "First child!", _ref: "../.."},
  {bar: "Second child!", _ref: "../.."}
 ]
}
```

(Note: If I don't put _ref, B objects are saved but without reference to A, ie, null values.)

And I have a Restfull Controller like:

```
class AController extends RestfullController {
 static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
 AController() {
  super(A)
 }
}
```

But, when I try to save my object, I got:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - TransientObjectException occurred when processing request: [POST] /example/a/save.json
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: mx.gob.morelos.ppi.Proyecto. Stacktrace follows:
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: A
    Line | Method
->>   99 | $tt__save in grails.rest.RestfulController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

What I need to do to save my JSON with their relations?

Regards.

Comment: I have same problem, do you got any solution?